# efficient sieve of Euler in stream processing style

Tags: haskell, primes, lazy-sequences, sieve

**Sieve of euler** has a better asymptotic complexity than **Sieve of Eratosthenes**, and can be implemented simply in Imperative languages.

I'm wondering wether there is any way to implement it elegantly with streams .I've checked the [haskell wiki about prime numbers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Euler.27s_Sieve), but the 2 implementations are hundreds times slower than other sieves (even trial division!) in that wiki.

so I try to write on my own:

```
{-sieve of Euler-}
primesEU = 2:sieve [3,5 ..] where
    sieve (p:i:xt) = p:(sieve (i:xt) `minus` (lps i)) where
        lps i = map (i*) (takeWhile' (\p->(p<i)&&(mod i p /= 0)) primesEU)

takeWhile'::(t->Bool)->[t]->[t]
takeWhile' p [] = []
takeWhile' p (x:xs) = case (p x) of
    True  -> x:takeWhile' p xs
    False -> [x]

minus::(Ord t) => [t]->[t]->[t]
minus [] _ = []
minus xs [] = xs 
minus xs@(x:xt) ys@(y:yt) 
                      |x<y  = x:(minus xt ys)
                      |x==y = minus xt yt
                      |x>y  = minus xs yt
```

`minus` is similar to `minus` in `Data.List.Ord`.

`takeWhile'` is similar to `takeWhile`, but has a minor difference: `takeWhile` drops the first element which not satisfies the predicate; `takeWhile'` will take it.

`lsp i` returns a finite stream of products of i and primes no more than i's least prime factor.

Sadly, my implementation runs **incredibly slow** ... and I can't find the culprit.

Anyway, is it possible to implement a efficient sieve of Euler in stream processing style ? Or the algorithm has something  inherent does against the nature of stream ?

Comment: "and can be implemented both simply and efficiently in Imperative languages." That's news to me. How would you efficiently implement it in an imperative language?

Comment: @DanielFischer my fault, my English is not good

Comment: Check out [the `primes` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primes/0.2.1.0/doc/html/Data-Numbers-Primes.html) for a quality implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman don't know what is quality, but you can compare haskellwiki's runtime at http://ideone.com/p0e81 with that of the package you linked to, at http://ideone.com/FqjMjz - the best version from haskellwiki, TMWE, **runs more than twice faster** than the code from the package you linked.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The implementation in [NumberSieves](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberSieves) is about twice as fast and uses about half the space (scales a bit better too). My implementation of the same algorithm (as the `NumberSieves`) in [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) about three times (and uses a bit less memory than `NumberSieves`), not to speak of the Eratosthenes sieve in `arithmoi`. The `primes` implementation is not good (but orders of magintude better than [`Numbers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Numbers), I'll give it that).

Comment: Euler's optimization doesn't make sense today, because multiplication is much cheaper than memory access. And streams or lists are much worse than bit arrays anyway.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to ``sieve = foldr (\i-> (i :) . (`minus` lps i)) []``. This is **not** an [Euler's sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Euler.27s_Sieve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
primesEU = 2:sieve [3,5 ..] where
    sieve (p:i:xt) = p:(sieve (i:xt) `minus` (lps i)) where
        lps i = map (i*) (takeWhile' (\p->(p<i)&&(mod i p /= 0)) primesEU)
```

First of all, the implementation is incorrect, it considers 9 prime. I suspect you meant `` sieve (i:xt) `minus` lps p `` there.

Then, since the sieved list contains only odd numbers, you can restrict to `tail primesEU` in `lps`, which makes a small difference.

So what is happening here?

The gist of it (I'm off to dinner in a moment, will expand when I come back) is that each prime `p` has to bubble through all the `minus` calls created by the odd numbers (`>= 3`) smaller than `p` [not quite, a few `minus` are eliminated before]. That's `(p-3)/2` layers, each costing one step.

So, constant factors and composites aside, producing the primes `<= n` costs `O(∑ p)`, where the sum is over the primes not greater than `n`. That's `O(n²/log n)`.

Let us follow a few steps of the evaluation of `sieve [3,5 .. ]`. For brevity, I denote by `s k` the list `sieve [k, k+2 ..]` and `minus` by `(\\)`. I use the corrected definition

```
sieve (k:ks) = k : (sieve ks `minus` lps k)
```

that doesn't consider 9 prime. I expand the list of multiples immediately, which reduces the work somewhat. We get

```
 (:)
 / \
3  (\\)
   /  \
 s 5  [9]
```

immediately, and the 3 can then be consumed directly. After that, the `minus` topping the right subtree demands that `s 5` be evaluated enough to tell whether it's empty.

```
   (\\)
   /  \
 (:)  [9]
 / \
5  (\\)
   /  \
 s 7  [15,25]
```

That's done in one step. (Then it needs to be determined whether `lps 3` is empty, and similarly later, but for each member of a `lps k`, it's only one step, so we can ignore that.) Then `minus` needs a comparison to bubble the 5 to the top, leaving

```
   (:)
   / \
  5  (\\)
     /  \
  (\\)  [9]
  /  \
s 7  [15,25]
```

Now, after the 5 has been consumed, the right child of the top `(:)` needs to be expanded

```
      (\\)
      /  \
   (\\)  [9]
   /  \
 (:)  [15,25]
 / \
7  (\\)
   /  \
 s 9  [21,35,49]
```

One comparison to move the 7 past the multiples of 5

```
     (\\)
     /  \
   (:)  [9]
   / \
  7  (\\)
     /  \
  (\\)  [15,25]
  /  \
s 9  [21,35,49]
```

and one more to lift it past the multiple of 3

```
      (:)
      / \
     7  (\\)
        /  \
     (\\)  [9]
     /  \
  (\\)  [15,25]
  /  \
s 9  [21,35,49]
```

After moving the 7 past two lists of composites, it has become ready for consumption. After that, the right subtree of the top-level `(:)` here must be evaluated further to determine the next prime (if there is any). The evaluation must step down three levels of `(\\)` in the tree, to reach the `s 9` that provides the next candidate.

```
         (\\)
         /  \
      (\\)  [9]
      /  \
   (\\)  [15,25]
   /  \
 (:)  [21,35,49]
 / \
9  (\\)
   /  \
 s 11 [27]
```

That candidate must be lifted past two `minus`es to finally reach the `minus` that eliminates it

```
        (\\)
        /  \
     (\\)  [9]
     /  \
   (:)  [15,25]
   / \
  9  (\\)
     /  \
  (\\)  [21,35,49]
  /  \
s 11 [27]

        (\\)
        /  \
      (:)  [9]
      / \
     9  (\\)
        /  \
     (\\)  [15,25]
     /  \
  (\\)  [21,35,49]
  /  \
s 11 [27]
```

Now the `minus` can do its work for the first time, producing

```
           (\\)
           /  \
        (\\)  []
        /  \
     (\\)  [15,25]
     /  \
  (\\)  [21,35,49]
  /  \
s 11 [27]
```

(the `` xs `minus` [] `` at the top eliminates the empty list only after the first argument has been determined non-empty; swapping the first two equations of `minus` would change that, but the difference in steps needed would be small). Then the evaluation must step down four levels in the tree to produce the next candidate (11). That candidate must be lifted past four `minus` until it reaches the top. One `minus` is eliminated from the tree in the course of that, so the next candidate (13) is produced only four levels down the tree, and not five (`(13-3)/2`), thus the number of steps to bring `p` to the top so that it may be consumed is not quite `(p-3)/2`, but it's not much less.

The last element in an `lps k` is always divisible by the square of the smallest prime factor of `k`, and they are all odd, so there are at most

```
1/2*(n/3² + n/5² + n/7² + n/11² + ...) ~ n/10
```

lists that can be eliminated when reaching `n` (there are a few less, since that counts all numbers having a square prime divisor, and those having more than one multiple times).

So the problem is that each prime is produced deep down in the tree, at least `p*0.4` levels from the top. That means lifting `p` to the top to make it consumable takes at least `p*0.4` steps, giving a basically quadratic overall complexity, not counting the work needed to produce the lists of multiples.

However, the actual behaviour is worse at first, it nears quadratic behaviour when computing primes in the region between 100000 and a 200000 - should become quadratic modulo logarithmic factors in the limit, but I don't think I have the patience to wait for a million or two.

> Anyway, is it possible to implement a efficient sieve of Euler in stream processing style? Or the algorithm has something inherent does against the nature of stream?

I can't prove it's impossible, but I know of no way to implement it efficiently. Neither as producing a stream of primes, nor as producing a list of primes to a given limit.

What makes the Sieve of Eratosthenes efficient is that it is trivial to reach the next multiple of a prime (just add `p` or `2*p` or so to the index) without caring whether it has already been crossed off as a multiple of a smaller prime. The work needed to avoid multiple crossings-off is much more than the work of the multiple crossings-off.

Comment: If the problem is that you are building up a stack of filters under which is the stream you want to filter, why don't you just keep track of the filters manually? Essentially, instead of having `stream \\ [] \\ [15, 25] \\ [21, 35, 49] \\ [27]`, force it into a pattern like `stream \\ (merge [27] $ merge [21, 35, 49] $ merge [15, 25] [])`. I don't know if that would work, but it is a promising direction to go in.